# Get results count in Left Join in Laravel

Tags: laravel, query-builder

I am doing a Left Join where I would like to get the data from a table and the count of the appearance of the ID of another table, I have the table:

`'tab_areas_atuacoes'`

which is a specialty of a professional, and I have the table

`'tab_medicos_as_area_atuacao'`

which is the table that has all the specialities of each professional, where each professional can have more than one speciality.

I want to get the data from `'tab_areas_atuacoes'` and I want to get the amount of specialties that each professional has, but I'm not getting results. Could someone give me some idea? So far I have this:

```
DB::table('tab_areas_atuacoes')                         
   ->whereNull('deleted_at')
   ->leftJoin('tab_medicos_as_areas_de_atuacao', function($query){
        $query->on('tab_medicos_as_areas_de_atuacao.rel_area_atuacao_id', 'tab_areas_atuacoes.esp_id');
        $query->selectRaw('tab_medicos_as_areas_de_atuacao.*, count(tab_medicos_as_areas_de_atuacao.rel_area_atuacao_id) as total');                                                                                 
   })->select('esp_id', 'esp_data', 'esp_titulo', 'esp_status', 'deleted_at')->groupBy('tab_areas_atuacoes.esp_id');
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I had a go working out what you want but if I got it wrong it would be helpful if you could post some example data along with the result set you would expect to get from it.

Comment: You already passed what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid I don't really understand the structure so there was a bit of guesswork involved here. You had a select within your join, I'm not sure if you were actually trying to add all those columns to the result set or not. You can add all the columns you need to the initial select or add others later with an `addSelect()` call.

```php
DB::table('tab_areas_atuacoes')
  ->select(
    'esp_id',
    'esp_data',
    'esp_titulo',
    'esp_status',
    'deleted_at',
    DB::raw(
      'COUNT(tab_medicos_as_areas_de_atuacao.rel_area_atuacao_id) AS total'
    )
  )->leftJoin(
    'tab_medicos_as_areas_de_atuacao',
    'tab_medicos_as_areas_de_atuacao.rel_area_atuacao_id',
    '=',
    'tab_areas_atuacoes.esp_id'
  )->whereNull('deleted_at')
  ->groupBy('tab_areas_atuacoes.esp_id'));
```